# Is there a standard pattern for implementing state machines using java?

Tags: java

One way i could think about is having a class which listens to events and has the different states stored in variables.

Is there a standard pattern for implementing state machines using java?

Answer (score 6):

The article I read before seems to be down right now, but if you Google enough you should be able to find other sources on how to implement **finite state machines** using Java `enum`s.

Found it: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/java-secret-using-enum-to-build-state.html

Answer (score 1):

[state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) can be used. See an example implementation in C++ [here](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/umlfsm.pdf).

Comment: The 2nd link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Use a state pattern, as described here: [State Design Pattern using java .. A different approach!](http://blogs.oracle.com/jkumaran/entry/state_design_pattern_using_java)

Answer (score 0):

There's [jBPM](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm), which can run standalone. It's essentially a persistent state machine with bells and whistles.